# "undefined is not a function" error when what's referenced is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to figure out why this specific line in my code keeps saying that 'undefined is not a function'. [Associated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXkrUrL715RKJcuLy2hi?p=preview)

```
// This line displays the function to be invoked
console.log((compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem] || noop))
// This line displays that the bitwise selection is really a function
console.log(angular.isFunction(compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem] || noop))
// Invocation with context that displays 'undefined is not a function'
(compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem] || noop).apply(this, arguments)
```

I'm just confused as to why it shows that error when clearly the bitwise selection results to a function. I know that I can check if `compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem]` is defined and then invoke it, but this problem is really bugging me. If someone can shed light to this mystery I would really appreciate it.

**Update:**

Another weird behvaiour is when you assign the invocation to a variable or return it, it doesn't show the 'undefined is not a function' error anymore.

e.g.

```
var fn = (compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem] || noop).apply(this, arguments)
```

or

```
return (compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem] || noop).apply(this, arguments)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're beginning the relevant statement with a paren, you need to end the previous with a semicolon. You haven't done so in your Plunker. Simply add a semicolon to your previous statement and you will not see the error:

```
tElem.addClass('form-control');
(compileStrategies[tAttr.bsFormItem] || noop).apply(this, arguments)
```

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MVKQL8stMBAYA7WzAyH9?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks.. I figured it out like 5 minutes ago, I have read an explanation regarding Automatic Semicolon Insertion in javascript @ http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9.